# Is this the correct differentiation of $r (t) = r\cos(\omega t +\phi) - r\sin(\omega t + \phi)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I always see questions of this style around because they are so common in physics. Often we're asked to differentiate them so is this correct?

$$r'(t) = -\omega r\sin(\omega t +\phi) - \omega r\cos(\omega t + \phi)$$

Comment: You should replace $r$ with $a$ in the right side of the equation, if that's the cause of confusion?

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed correct.  Just a simple application of chain rule.

In general, $f(g(x))' = f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\cos(ax+b)=-a\sin(ax+b)$

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\sin(ax+b)=a\cos(ax+b)$

I think by this you can verify your answer.